# Scrapy can't reach callback for Request

Tags: python, scrapy

I use next code in my spider:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    item['price'] = [i for i in self.get_usd_price(response)]
    return item

def get_usd_price(self, response):
    yield FormRequest(
        'url',
        formdata={'key': 'value'},
        callback=self.get_currency
    )

def get_currency(self, response):
    self.log('lalalalala')
```

The problem is I can't reach my get_currency callback. In my logger I see that `price` item takes `[<POST url>]` value. What am I doing wrong? I tried to add `dont_filter` to FormRequest, change FormRequest to simple get Request

#### Update

I've also tried [GHajba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33361767/3606603)'s suggestion (so far without success):

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    self.get_usd_price(response, item)
    return item

def get_usd_price(self, response, item):
    request = FormRequest(
        'url',
        formdata={'key': 'value'},
        callback=self.get_currency
    )
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def get_currency(self, response):
    self.log('lalalalala')
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['price'] = 123
    return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how scrapy works, you can only yield a request or an item on every method, but you can't yield the response this way, If you want to update the price information for the item and then yield it you should do something like:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = MyItem()
    # populate the item with this response data
    yield FormRequest(
        'url',
        formdata={'key': 'value'},
        callback=self.get_currency, meta={'item':item}
    )

def get_currency(self, response):
    self.log('lalalalala')
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['price'] = 123 # get your price from the response body.
    # keep populating the item with this response data
    yield item
```

So check that for passing information between requests, you need to use the meta parameter.

Comment: Cool, now I reached my callback. But what if I have many item fields that depends on response in `parse_item`? Where should I handle them? Should I somehow pass `parse_item`'s response to callback or I can fill my other item field right in `parse_item`?

Comment: the second, you should treat the item on every callback as it is supposed to be, populate the item, and then pass it with the `meta` parameter to the following callback, then keep populating. If you need to populate the item with data from a third response, then keep passing the item on `meta`.

Comment: Yes! And then in very last callbak I finally return my item. Now I've got the idea. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you assign the values of the generator created in `get_usd_price` to your item. You can solve this with changing the method and how you call it.

You have to `yield` the `FormRequest` but you mustn't use this value to have an effect with Scrapy. Just call the function `get_usd_price` without assigning it to `item['price']`:

```
self.get_usd_price(response, item)
```

You have to provide `item` to your function because Scrapy works asynchronous so you cannot be sure when the `FormRequest` is executing. Now you have to pass along the `item` as a `meta` parameter of the `FormRequest` and then you can access the item in the `get_currency` function and `yield` the item there.

You can read more about `meta` in the docs: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But without any luck. I've updated my question.

Comment: If you do not do `yield request` in `get_usd_price` how do you expect Scrapy to call your Request?

Comment: Oh, I just forget to copy it. Still doesn't work for me.

Comment: And remove `return item` form `parse_item` because in this case you will return an unfinished item. Do you reach the `get_currency` function? And I expect you use the real URL as `url` and not the string as it is in your example...

Comment: I still can't reach `get_currency`. I even call `pdb.set_trace()` inside but no luck. And yes I use real url. I tried to change my request to simple GET-request to google and still nothing.